# Fill gradient numerically(by entering values)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

In Fireworks or Photoshop, is there any way to fill gradient with numerical precision? I'm not talking about setting up gradient but to **fill/apply** it.

Comment: As for now I have to manually draw the line of gradient by hand. I would like to draw that line by numerical values.

Comment: Oh, okey. Might be clearer if you phrased it that way. By "num prec." people usually think of something else. No biggie, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do exactly that...
BUT
you can create guides (by dragging from the ruler ctrl/cmd-R) that intersect the exact points you wish to draw from and two, so that when dragging the gradient tool, the cursor snaps to those intersections points (provided you have snap to guides turned on).